# Avoid calling indexchanged event when filling datasoruce

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm filling a combobox with the datasource property in a c# winform app. In the other hand, I'm firing up an action with the SelectedIndexChanged of the same combo. The problem is that whenever the combo is filled with datasource the SelectedIndexChanged is called and I just want this event to be called when the user in fact does a selection.
Is there a way to avoid calling this event when filling the combo?

This is some of my code

```
//Filling the combo with some data
combo_cliente.DataSource = clientes;
combo_cliente.DisplayMember = "NomComp";
combo_cliente.ValueMember = "IDPersona";

private void combo_cliente_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here is the action to be triggered when user perfoms a selection
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a simple boolean switch. Before setting datasource set it to `true` and after set to `false`. In event handler do not do anything if the value of the switch is `true`

Comment: I've already thought of that but I just wanted to know if there is a "fancy" way of do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe unsubscribe and then subscribe again:

```
combo_cliente.SelectedIndexChanged -= combo_cliente_SelectedIndexChanged;
combo_cliente.DataSource = clientes;
combo_cliente.SelectedIndexChanged += combo_cliente_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

im assuming you assigned the event handler with the designer so they are bound when the control is instantiated. alternatively you could assign them in code after populating the controls.

Comment: The fact is that my combo is populated in comboboxselectedindexchagned of another combo, so could be populated more than once in runtime.

Comment: so in the other combobox selected index changed, detach the handler from this combobox,  set the datasource, and then reattach the handler.

Comment: @dumdum how do I detach the handler? I attached the event using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Attach your event handler in your code behind instead of doing it on your aspx page and do it affer you have finished loading your control.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a blank record as the first of your combobox. Then in your code, you can write this;

`private void combo_cliente_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if!(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()== string.Empty)
            {
            //Here is the action to be triggered when user perfoms a selection
            }
        }`